# Firestore get call

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, promise

i need some understanding and a solution.

I have a seperate js-file where i handle all api calls.

So i want in my HomeScreen get the Data from firestore back.

In the Api in the then call i get my data but in the Home Screen i get only a Promise back.

I try some changes out but nothing helps. I do not understand this.
How i get in my HomeScreen the data?

Is something with my code wrong?

Api.js

```
export const getCurrentUserProfile = () => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    const userDocID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const docRef = db.collection('Users').doc(userDocID);

    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.data()); // return the data i need
        return doc.data();
      } else {
        console.log('No document for this ID: undefined');
      }

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting document', error);
    });
  }
  
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
const user = getCurrentUserProfile();
console.log(user);
// And here i get this back:
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}

const user = getCurrentUserProfile().then(data => console.log(data));
// this return as well undefined
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that Promises are async, and basically they are only that - promises. If you need the actual data from a promise to work with, you have 2 options:

- Either chain callbacks after them with `.then()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then))
- Use the `await` keyword ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await))

Secondly, currently you don't return anything from your getCurrentUserProfile() function. You need to return the `docRef.get()` method, which is a promise itself, and will resolve to `doc.data()`.

Example:

```
// option 1
const user = getCurrentUserProfile().then(data => console.log(data));

// option 2
const user = await getCurrentUserProfile();
console.log(user);
```

Keep in mind, that you can only use `await` inside an async function.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I try it out but I get null on option 1. If I delete in api the return null i get undefined back and an error

Comment: @juri88 What happens when you extract doc.data() before returning? Something like this: ```const response = doc.data(); return response;```

Comment: the same error :( TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'(0,_Api.getCurrentUserProfile().then')

Comment: Oh, wait. try to return your whole docRef.get() statement. So put a ```return``` keyword before ```docRef.get().... ```

Comment: THANK YOU, now i get the data, but only in then if console.log(user); i get another Promise? WHY ? Do you know? And why i have to return the whole doc.ref?

Answer (score 0):

Now I get an another Error. Invalid Hook Call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. But i need only once to initialise the user to useState to access the Object. How i can do that?

Because if i move the code inside the component it runs every second...

```
const [userObj, setUserObj] = useState({});
getCurrentUserProfile().then(user => {
  setUserObj(user);
});

const HomeScreen = props => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text style={globalStyles.h1}>Home</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
};
```